# Date and time widget in Dojo

Tags: javascript, date, time, dojo

Dojo has two widgets:

- Date textbox: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/DateTextBox.html
- Time textbox: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/TimeTextBox.html

NOTE: I am using Dojo programmatically.

I want the user to enter a date and a time, and then send the server the "mixed" value of the lot (that is, that date + time).

I realise that I need to manipulate the two values before the `submt()`. Is there an established way to do this? Surely I am not the only person on the planet needing a simple Date/Time form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you use:

```
registry.byId("myTimeTxtBox").get("value");
```

You get a `Date` object containing the time value and the date is the epoch itself. This means that if you select 1 AM, it will return the time at `01-01-1970 01:00:00`.
You can then retrieve the unix timestamp (number of milliseconds since `01-01-1970 00:00:00`) which will give you the amount of time in milliseconds by doing:

```
var timeEpoch = registry.byId("myTimeTxtBox").get("value").getTime();
```

If you do the same with your date textbox:

```
var dateEpoch = registry.byId("myDateTxtBox").get("value").getTime();
```

And add both to each other, you will get the UNIX timestamp of your date + time, converting it back to a `Date` object is easy as well:

```
new Date(dateEpoch + timeEpoch);
```

I also made a small [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FjuCa/) to demonstrate.

Comment: Thank you! I think you are going to get a lot of upvotes over time with this answer!

Comment: It doesn't work! Do this 1) Set your timezone to Rome. 2) Set as date 02/04/2014 3) Set at time 1:42. NOW, a fact: 1:42 Rome time is 11:42 UTC time. However, the result of your fiddle is `Wed Apr 02 2014 00:42:00 GMT+0200 (CEST) ` which actually is 10:42 UTC time! The problem is that the time ALSO has a timezone. I fixed the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/FjuCa/1/ Am I missing something?